# Erro após executar uma ação redirecionar para uma página

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Acredito que estou passando errado o código abaixo, ele deveria depois de salvar o Cliente e redirecionar para página Cliente/Index, porém depois de salvar fica na mesma página, usando o Debug ele passa no Cliente/Index(Action e View), mas não abre a página

```
 public ActionResult Cadastro(Cliente cliente)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (IsCpf(cliente.CPF).Equals(true))
            {
                db.Cliente.Add(cliente);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
                ViewBag.Mensagem = "CPF Inválido"; 
        }

        ViewBag.Estados = new SelectList(SelecionarEstados(), "Value", "Text");
        return View(cliente);

    }

public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Cliente.Where(s => s.Ativo == true).ToList());
    }
```

Minha View Index
Obs: Usando o *Debug* ele passa na *ACTION* Index, Depois passa na *View* Index, corre o *foreach* normal, só não renderiza.

```
@model IEnumerable<SistemaComercial.Models.Cliente>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Clientes";
<link href="~/Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@* ----- Boostrap ----- *@
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
}

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href=''>Home</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href='http://localhost:63729/Cliente/Index'>Cliente</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href='http://localhost:63729/Entrada/Index'>Entrada</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href='http://localhost:63729/Fornecedor/Index'>Fornecedor</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href='http://localhost:63729/Produto/Index'>Produto</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href='http://localhost:63729/Usuario/Index'>Usuário</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href='http://localhost:63729/Gerencial/Index'>Relatórios</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="http://localhost:63729/Venda/Index">Venda</a></li>
</ul>
<h2 class="text-primary">Listagem de Clientes</h2>
<button class="btn btn-link" formmethod="get" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Cadastro", "Cliente")'">Cadastrar Novo Cliente</button>
<table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
<tr>
    <th>
        Código
    </th>
    <th>
        CPF
    </th>
    <th>
        Nome Completo
    </th>
    <th>
        Data de Nascimento
    </th>       
    <th>
        Opções
    </th>
</tr>

@foreach (var clientes in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => clientes.Codigo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => clientes.CPF)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => clientes.NomeCompleto)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => clientes.DataNascimento)
        </td>        

        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-default details" data-id="@clientes.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" data-id="@clientes.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary edit" data-id="@clientes.Codigo"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></button>
        <td>
    </tr>
}
</table>

<div class="modal" id="modal">

</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/Own/ScriptsModal.js"></script>

<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

@section Scripts{
@* ----- Jquery ----- *@
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.intellisense.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
@* ----- Bootstrap ----- *@


}
```

Minha View Cadastro

```
@model SistemaComercial.Models.Cliente

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Cadastro";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterPageCadastro.cshtml";
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
}
 <h2 class="text-primary text-center">Cadastro de Cliente</h2>

 @using (Html.BeginForm())
 {
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

 <fieldset class="scheduler-border">
    <legend class="scheduler-border"></legend>
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        <div class="editor-label">
            CPF
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CPF)
        </div><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            Nome Completo
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NomeCompleto, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NomeCompleto)
        </div><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            Data de Nascimento
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DataNascimento)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataNascimento)
        </div><br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            CEP
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CEP)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CEP)
        </div><br />
        <div class="editor-label">
            Logradouro
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Logradouro)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Logradouro)
        </div> <br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            Numero
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Numero)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Numero)
        </div><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            Bairro
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bairro)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bairro)
        </div><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            Cidade
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cidade)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cidade)
        </div><br />

        <div class="editor-label">
            Estado
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Estados")

        </div><br />

        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index","Cliente")'">Cancelar</button>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar (F5)" id="AjaxPost" />
        <br />
        <div id="content">

        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
}

@*<script>
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".DataNascimento").mask("99/99/9999", { placeholder: "dd/mm/yyyy" });
    $("#CPF").mask("999.999.999-99");
    $("#CEP").mask("99.999-999");
 });
 </script>*@



<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#AjaxPost").click(function () {

        var dataObject = {  
            Logradouro: $("#Logradouro").val(),
            Numero: $("#Numero").val(),
            Bairro: $("#Bairro").val(),
            Cidade: $("#Cidade").val(),
            Estado: $("#Estados").val(),
            CEP: $("#CEP").val(),
            CPF: $("#CPF").val(),
            Ativo: true,
            NomeCompleto: $("#NomeCompleto").val(),
            DataNascimento: $("#DataNascimento").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Cadastro","Cliente")",
            type: "GET",
            data: dataObject,
            dataType: "json",
        });

    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Poderia postar sua action Index?
No banco o Cliente é salvo? Ele realmente chama o `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cliente");`

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta... É salvo sim.

Comment: A action Cadastro está no mesmo controller do seu index? Se sim tente substituir o return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cliente"); Por return Index();

Comment: Já tentei, mas continua na mesma página ainda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vejo nada "errado" em seu código para não funcionar, a não esse `try` em sua Action Index.
Se como você disse, está salvando no banco e redirecionando, pode ser que esse esteja chamando o `catch` em sua Action.

Aconselho algumas melhorias em seu código, que são:

Utilize [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx) em suas propriedades para certificar dos dados, dentre outras opções, ficando assim o seu Model Cliente.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório")]
public string CPF { get; set; }
```

Em seu controller, você verifica somente se está válido ou não. Não precisa desse `if else` que você adicionou, ficando assim:

```
public ActionResult Cadastro( Cliente cliente)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //Se for controller diferente, mude para isso: return RedirectToAction("Index","Cliente"); Lembrando de ter certeza que existe a Action Index no Controller Cliente.(Tem que ser escrito corretamente)
    }

    ViewBag.Estados = new SelectList(SelecionarEstados(), "Value", "Text");
    return View(cliente);
}
```

E em sua Action Index, não há necessidade alguma de utilizar o `try catch`, você simplesmente retorna os dados para a `View`.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View(db.Cliente.Where(s => s.Ativo).ToList());
}
```

Caso `db.Cliente.Where(s => s.Ativo).ToList())` e você esteja usando alguma propriedade, basta verificar em sua `view` se a lista está `null` ou não, desta forma:

```
@if(Model != null){
   //Coloque aqui o que precisar
}
```

### EDIÇÃO

Você não está utilizando o `form` para salvar o dado, logo o `RedirectToAction()` não irá funcionar mesmo. Se você quer mesmo utilizar `ajax`, você deve ir para a `view` no evento **success** do `ajax`. Para isso, altere sua `action` para o verificar se a requisição está vindo por um **request Ajax** ou não, desta forma:

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    db.Clientes.Add(cliente);
    db.SaveChanges();
    //Se não for via ajax ele direciona para a action
      if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {
         return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
     return RedirectToAction("Index"); Lembrando de ter certeza que existe a Action Index no Controller Cliente.(Tem que ser escrito corretamente)
}
```

E seu código `ajax` você altera para direcionar para a página específica, desta forma:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("Cadastro","Cliente")",
            type: "GET",
            data: dataObject,
            dataType: "json",
             success: function (response) {
                location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Cliente")'; //Sua Action aqui
            }
        });
```

Lembrando que desta forma você perde muitas qualidades do [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc), como as validações por exemplo. Aconselho você utilizar o `form` normalmente, já que você quer redirecionar a página. Para isso, basta alterar seu botão para realizar o submit, que está assim:

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar (F5)" id="AjaxPost" />
```

Para isso:

```
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Salvar (F5)" />
```

Feito isso, você não irá mais precisar do código `Ajax` para salvar os dados.

> Lembrando que a Microsoft possui o [Ajax.BeginForm()](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ajax.beginform()) para trabalhar com Ajax em MVC.

Comment: Atualizei minha pergunta, com suas sugestões, porém ainda não funciona.

Comment: @J.C.Galhardi poderia adicionar sua `view` Cadastro?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: @J.C.Galhardi A view Cadastro. Que vai para a action `public ActionResult Cadastro( Cliente cliente)`

Comment: @J.C.Galhardi Editei a resposta, veja se lhe atende agora

Comment: Pelo que parece, não está caindo no _success_ do  ajax

Comment: Com usei o _Html.BeginForm()_ mesmo, agora está funcionando.

Comment: @J.C.Galhardi Foi falha minha. Editei a resposta novamente, veja se lhe atende agora